# How do I record all terminal input and output to a local file by default for each session?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal, command-history

I'm aware the `script` command can be used to record all keyboard input and screen output to a file, but this has to be invoked each time a terminal session is started. I keep timestamped versions of my .bash_history files so old commands aren't lost after $HISTSIZE is reached. My $HISTFILE statement in .bashrc is `HISTFILE=~/.bash_history_$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S_%N').txt`. That satisfies my need to create a log of commands executed, but doesn't record the output to a file. Is there something I can put in .bashrc or .profile that will record all stdin input, and stdout & stderr output to a timestamped file? This would be handy to monitor user activity as well, but I just need it to reference in the future.

**EDIT**:
I found that if I put

`script /ramdisk/consoleOutput_$(whoami)_$(date +'%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_%N').txt ; exit`

at the end of ~/.profile, for a test user, this behaved like I want.

The extra `;exit` after the `script` command exits from the terminal. Typing "exit" when the user is logged in exits the `script` session. When that exits from ~/.profile, the extra "exit" then quits the SSH/terminal session. I plan on creating additional functionality which will `chown` the file to root and `chmod 600` so only root can read it. From there, it'll be moved to a secure location.

Furthermore, the coloring is visible with `cat` and `more`. Opening it in an editor shows the control characters used to generate the color. I'm okay with that.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to monitor the system, you want `pam_tty_audit`. As the name implies, `pam_tty_audit` is a [pam module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) which when configured properly, is invoked any time a user opens a session (and gets a TTY). The module records all input & output, and sends everything it records to the [auditd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd) daemon. You can then execute queries against the auditd daemon to view the logs.

RedHat provides a nice guide on getting started with `pam_tty_audit`: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sec-Configuring_PAM_for_Auditing.html
For distros not based on RedHat or Fedora, the guide still works, but might need slight tweaks for the filenames in `/etc/pam.d/`.

Note that it's not completely foolproof. There are ways to execute commands without a TTY. For example when connecting via ssh, you can do `ssh foo.example.com bash -i`, and because a command was specified, no TTY is allocated. Though there are things you can do to prevent this.

You also want to make sure access to the log is secured. `pam_tty_audit` records **ALL** TTY activity, this includes passwords you type in.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want passwords showing up though.

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* want to, you could make a program (or shell script) which calls `script` writing to a timestamped "typescript" file (and in turn calling your real shell) and make *that* program your default shell in `/etc/passwd`.

There are a few pitfalls:

- you may have to add this program to `/etc/shells`
- doing this sets the `SHELL` environment variable, which is used in various ways.  Override that to avoid loops (and other misbehavior):

```
    #!/bin/sh
    SHELL=/bin/bash
    export SHELL
    script -c "$SHELL" $HOME/consoleOutput_$(whoami)_$(date +'%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_%N').txt
```

Comment: I'll try that with a test user and see how well it works.

Comment: I put the following in an executable script
`#!/bin/bash`
`script -a "/ramdisk/consoleOutput.txt"`
`/bin/bash`
and as a login shell, it loops infinitely. I can kill it with Ctrl+C and type `exit` until all those loops have exited. I can execute the program after I already login and it works as intended. Did I not do something correct with the script? After that part is working, I'll add the timestamp feature.